# Red Hat 6 - Httpd24 - Django - mod_wsgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, httpd

me encuentro con servidor con SO Red Hat 6, éste por defecto viene con un servicio httpd que no deseamos usar. Por tanto instalamo httpd 2.4.18 como un segundo servicio apache. Más o menos en éste [link](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/01/using-apache-httpd-2-4-rhel6/) se puede identificar como se realizó.

Ahora queremos enlazar el servicio http24 con Django usando mod_wsgi.

Esto ya se realizó pruebas en otro servidor(centos7) desde cero, por lo que al usar

```
yum install mod_wsgi
```

se instalaba el mod en único apache de este servidor de pruebas.

En el nuevo servidor, el cual es red hat, al usar el mismo comando se instala el mod_wsgi en el apache que viene por defecto y no el nuevo http24.

Mi pregunta sería, existe alguna manera directa para indicar a yum como instalar el mod/complemente de wsgi en el http24?
o en su defecto, Como hacer la instalación sin yum del mod_wsgi y que sea directa al httpd24?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, se entrego solución por parte del soporte de red hat.
Pensamos a futuro cambiar el servidor ared hat 7 para no tener inconvenientes de esta índole.